# Simple Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the given program Class B has inherited Class A and in main() object of class B is created and getdata() function is invoked, why does class B's getdata() is called??

```
class A {public: void getdata() { cout<<"Class A"; } };

class B: public A { public: void getdata() { cout<<"Class B"; } };

void main() { B b1; b1.getdata(); }
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: As i know in inheritance always base class function should be called.

Comment: tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm Check out the above link. Why does always parent class area function is called?

Comment: if you want base class function to be called you have to explicitly make that happen by coding `A::getdata()`

Answer (score 4):

> why does class B's getdata() is called??

Because `b1` is an object of type `B`.

Non-`virtual` member functions are resolved according to the *static type* of the variable that invokes them.

In the case you gave, the variable that invokes `getdata()` is `b1`, which is of type `B`. Therefore, `B::getdata()` is invoked.

In the link you provided, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm , `area` is invoked through a pointer of type `Shape*`, therefore, `Shape::area()` is invoked.

Consider also this program: http://ideone.com/KVjN3

```
#include <iostream>

class A {public: void getdata() { std::cout<<"Class A\n"; } };

class B: public A { public: void getdata() { std::cout<<"Class B\n"; } };

int main() { B b1; b1.getdata(); A* pa = &b1; pa->getdata(); }
```

output:

```
Class B
Class A
```

It is very similar to your program. The first invocation of `getdata()` is through a `B`, therefore `B::getdata()` is invoked. The second is through an `A*`, therefore `A::getdata()` is invoked.

All of this changes, however, if you supply the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm
Check out the above link. Why does always parent class area function is called?

Comment: The first example in that link, the only example without the `virtual` keyword, differs from yours in an important way. It uses pointers and you don't. If ytou had created an `A*` that points to `b1`, then you would have seen the behavior you expected.

Comment: @user1581595 - Consider this program: http://ideone.com/KVjN3 and why it behaves as it does.

Comment: @user1581595 - You are welcome. May I ask two favors? First, please *vote* for each answer that helped you and *accept* the most helpful one. Second, in future please include a **complete** program in your question, that is one that I might copy-paste and compile. Don't remove `#include` or `using` statements. See http://sscce.org for why that is important.

Comment: It is obviously your answer is the best dude.

Comment: @user1581595 - in that case, please **accept** the best answer by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because `b1` is declared statically as a variable of type `B`.

Note that in this situation the fact that `getdata()` is not virtual is not relevant because of the reason written here above.

Answer (score 0):

C++ objects aren't polymorphic by nature (as opposed to Java).
You have to declare the functions with the "virtual" key in order to achieve polymorphism

Comment: But, even if he had declared `virtual getdata()`, he **still** would've invoked `B::getdata()`.